# Check if a collection of edges forms a loop

Tags: python, mesh

I'm looking for the best code to check if a collection of edges forms a closed loop.

The input data is an array of edges, with each edge (= line segment) being defined by it's two endpoints. For example: `[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,1]]` represents 4 edges: the first connecting point `1` with point `2`, etc, where `1`, `2`,... are some unique labels for each point (i.e. `1` might represent a point `(1,1,2)`).

The example above is a closed loop. A different example might be: `[[44,52],[69,71],[8,101],[52,77],[71,77],[69,8]` does not represent a closed loop, since starting at point `44`, we would connect `44->52->77->71->69->8->101` doesn't end at `44`. Notice also that: each edge can have the two points in any order, and the order of the edges is also random (although you could of course sort them).

I'm looking for the best code to determine whether or not the loop is closed or not. "Best" needs to also maximize efficiency - the application is in mesh generation, and needs to determine loops/not-loops for a lot of different sets of edges, each comprising order of magnitude 100 vertices.

Thanks for your help!

**Edit**

My attempt: something like each point should appear twice if it's a closed loop. So generally, flatten the list and check if any vertex only appears once. However, I'm not sure this wouldn't prevent any other structures from appearing (branches? etc)

```
flat = [x for sublist in pts for x in sublist]
single = [x for x in flat if flat.count(x) == 1]
if len(single) > 0:
   # Not a closed loop....
```

Answer (score 2):

The following process would test if there are cycles.

Consider the dictionary with keys as the vertexes and the values as the list of vertexes adjacent to it. From [ [1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,1]] you have {1:[2,4],2:[1,3],3:[2,4],4:[1,3]}.

Process each vertex from the list of keys. 
    Find the first vertex that has only 1 adjacent vertex. 
    Remove it from the dictionary and look at it's adjacent vertex. 
    IF the adjacent vertex has:

- 1 adjacent vertex the you have found an end point, remove it and go back to the remaining vertex list
- 2 adjacent vertexes, so that just one remains after removal of the
  leaf,continue to it's remaining adjacent vertex, removing it from the
  dictionary.
- 3 or more adjacent vertexes remove the vertex from the connection list
  of that vertex and go back to the remaining vertex list.
  When you return the the remaining vertex list find the first vertex that has only one adjacent vertex. IF the dictionary is empty the original graph had no cycles. If you can not find a vertex with 1 adjacent vertex, that is all the vertexes have 2 or more neighbors, then the original graph has cycles.

If you collect edges to a list as they are removed you can also generate a list of edges that are not part of a loop or cycle. If the subgraph ends in the empty list then then removed edge list are also not connected to any loop or cycle.

This process would partition the set of edges into one of three subsets. The set of edges part of dangling strings and branches disconnected from loops, those connected to but not part of a loop/cycle, and the remaining set.

This remaining dictionary contains edges that are part of one or more cycles or are part of a path connecting two loops. Think of two loops connected by a path of vertexes in a dumbbell shape. The weights at the end are the loops and the bar is a string of vertexes between the loops. Each vertex will have two or more adjacent vertexes but the graph contains edges that are not part of a loop.

The vertexes at the end points of the connections between cycles would be more likely among vertexes with an odd number of adjacent vertexes but this is not a unique or necessary property.  A path connecting loops in one context may be part of a loop in another context. Membership in a connecting path between cycles or in a cycle is a relative and non exclusive property of an edge. Consider this graph:

```
1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8->6
         4->1     7->9->10->2
```

The loop 2->3->4->5->6->7->8->9>->10->2 would contain the path of vertexes 4->5->6 between loops 1->2->3->4->1 and 6->7->8->6. Also vertexes 2, 4, 6 and 7 would have 3 adjacent vertexes.

To generate a list of edges that are in paths between cycles but not in any cycle, is a harder problem. You could generate a list of all the cycles, count how many cycles each edge belongs, and remove edges that are in zero cycles. Or it may be more efficient to use sets instead of counting. Create a set of edges in each cycle and subtract each of those sets from the set of all edges and you will be left with edges that are in connections between cycles/loops.

In either case you will need to find all the cycles. Finding the set of cycles will involve walking the graph. You may find the answer in counts of visits to vertexes and traversals of edges during the process of finding all the cycles.

Further thoughts:
Considering efficiency it really depends on what you are dealing with upstream.
The properties of your superset, subsets and how the subsets are selected is not well defined and these are important in finding the most efficient solution. Most efficient at each step may not be best overall and as always there are RAM/processing time trade-offs.

Doing the work to find connected subsets, which seems to be what your subsets are, would require tracking edges so total efficiency may be higher if you use the algorithm on the superset of vertexes first, then sort each subset of edges to produce two subsets of connected edges. One containing loops and the other with strings and trees.

Putting counting and collection in each step of the total process in debug, or exploratory analytical branches of your code can help find a good solution. One approach to this would be to use functions visit(vertex), and traverse(edge) or class methods vertex.visit() and edge.traverse(), and inject collection, counting, and removal through keyword arguments, decorators , or specialization of classes. You also might find a multi-process map-reduce solution.
Representations of a graph.
As long as there can only be one edge between two vertexes then the mesh maps to a graph not a multigraph which would have more complications mapping different representations.
A graph is a set of vertexes and a set of edges between them. Three main ways a graph can be represented are:

1. A set of vertexes , and a set of edges representing each edge as a
   pairs of vertexes. (If the graph is a connected graph the set of vertexes
   might be implicit in the list of edges.)
2. A set of vertexes and a list of vertexes adjacent to each vertex.
3. An nxn matrix where n is the count of vertexes. The matrix is usually
   1 or true where vertexes are connected by an edge and 0 or false where
   they are not.

Each representation makes different properties quickly accessible.

The Set of vertexes and edges is the most memory efficient for bi-directional graphs. You could represent the edges as two element sets since order does not matter and would make [1,2] = [2,1] automatic since both are the set {1,2}.

Matrix, or adjacency list representation for bi-directional graphs will be redundant. Each edge will be represented in the adjacency lists of both vertexes or as a reflection along a diagonal in the Matrix. If vertex a is adjacent to vertex b, vertex b is also adjacent to vertex a, and for matrix G, G[a,b] = G[b,a]. For graphs mapped from a mesh G[a,a]=0 (no reflexive graph edges.)

For traversal counting you will run into some limits to dictionary keys.Only hashable values can be used as dictionary keys. It's best in most cases to also keep the keys immutable. This means list,sets and dictionaries are not valid dictionary keys. You can use corresponding tuples of primitive types instead. The immutable set type can also be used.

Your problem may have enough complexity to warrant including a library like [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/).

There may be a faster test. It's even more likely that if I propose an algorithm to find the cycles a better one could be constructed that uses constraints of graphs mapped from meshes.
The search for all cycles in a graph is not trivial and will require further research. 
Loops in graph theory often refer to reflexive edges. That is an edge from a vertex to itself. Many theorems in graph theory explore the subset of graphs without these types of edges. For that reason searching for cycles rather than loops will be more helpful

For finding all the cycles there are many methods. You might also try the math question site. I found this explanation differentiating some of my loosely used terminology for example. [What is the difference between a loop, cycle and strongly connected components in Graph Theory?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490053/what-is-the-difference-between-a-loop-cycle-and-strongly-connected-components-i)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that uses NetworkX:

```
import networkx as nx

edges = [[1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [4,1]]
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_edges_from(edges)

try:
    cycle = nx.find_cycle(g)
    cycle = set(map(frozenset, cycle))
    edges = set(map(frozenset, edges))
    if cycle == edges:
        print("The edges form a loop")
    else: print("The edges don't form a loop")
except nx.exception.NetworkXNoCycle: 
    print("No cycle found")
```

We create an undirected graph and look for a cycle. If we find one, we compare the edges that form the loop with the input edges. If they match, the input edges form a loop.

These lines:

```
cycle = set(map(frozenset, cycle))
edges = set(map(frozenset, edges))
```

allow you to compare edges, independently of their order.

This solution isn't perfect because `nx.find_cycle` only returns the first cycle it finds, so you may get false negatives. At the very least, you'll know for sure that the edges don't form a loop if an exception is thrown.

You could loop through every cycle until you find one that matches the input edges, but I'm not sure how efficient that would be for large edge sets. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/joe-jordan/6548029) for a way to find all cycles in a graph using NetworkX. Maybe turn `find_all_cycles` into a generator function?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go about this might be to create an array of big size (max edge coordinate size) where all values are initially `-1`. When you get an edge of the form `[a,b]`, set `array[a] = b`.

When trying to find out if its a loop, start at any index where the value is not `-1` and follow the value.

So, from `array[a]= b`, you will go to `array[b] = c`. If any of the upcoming values is `-1`, it is an open loop but if you get back to where you started, it is a closed loop.